# Enable POST HTTP method on node http-server

Tags: angular, httpserver

I am using the node http-server in order to mock some REST services for Angular 2 development.

HTTP.get is working fine, but it seems that by default the node http-server does not allow for post method.

```
private readonly URL_PREFIX = "http://localhost:8080/";

public updateUserInfo(userToUpdate:User) : Observable <User>{
    return this.http
        .post(this.URL_PREFIX+"UpdateUser.json", JSON.stringify(userToUpdate), {headers: this.JSON_HEADERS})
        .map(response => response.json().user as User)
        ;
}
```

This gives the below error:

POST http://localhost:8080/UpdateUser.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Any hint how to by pass this? (either a clean solution or a hack?)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing headers

Comment: Hi, I do not think so. I am passing the below header, and it works fine using the GET method.      private readonly JSON_HEADERS = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});